# mysql order nearest geopoints

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order a really big table with almost 1M records, that have latitude and longitude.

I can't use a Having because sometimes the nearest place is 100Mi and sometimes 1000Mi

Any idea on how can I approach this problem? My database is fully indexed. I run Explain with my query and every JOIN has index (I have over 6 joins in this query)

Right now I'm using something like this, I know that is not the best way but I think that is not that expensive, like if I use COS()

```
SQRT(POW(p.latitude - 25.6875703, 2) + POW(p.longitude - -100.283252, 2)) as deltaLoc
```

and then I order the table ORDER BY deltaLoc ASC LIMIT 0,9;

By DB is growing really fast, and I'm expecting in the next month 1M new records

OR should i move to other DB?

FYI I got a VPS with 8GB Ram and 4 CPUS, I should increment this or its fine?

Thanks

Comment: What you *really want* is an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) index based on [great circle distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance); sadly, whilst [MySQL's spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/spatial-extensions.html) do include a [`SPATIAL INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) that is an R-tree, it's based on [Euclidean geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry).  The most sargable approach you'll be able to achieve with pure MySQL is to limit your searches to a bounding distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [spatial data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html), which has proper support for sorting by distances.

Euclidean distance does not work for Lat/Lng coordinates, which lie on a sphere. The distance corresponding to 10 degrees of longitude will be different depending on the latitude (this is 0 m at the poles).

I know this is straightforward using PostGIS in PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure how well supported this is in MySQL.

Comment: ...or just use Euclidean distance as a first order approximation and leave an extra margin for the 0.01% of your customers who live above the Arctic Circle.  Any slop can be handled in post-processing.

Comment: I would also recomend to go for postgres and postgis. Why re-invent the wheel?: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html

Comment: @fearless_fool: Euclidean geometry can indeed be a reasonable first approximation for distances that lie well away from the poles—but only if those distances are short.  The OP mentions distances of up to 1000 miles, for which Euclidean geometry could definitely throw up material problems.

Comment: @fearless_fool Using proper spatial indexing will be a first order effect on the cost of returning the a limited number of closest points. Without spatial indexing, you have to compute the distance for all points, then select the closest. With spatial indexing, you only have to compute the distance for those points that are closer in the spatial index.